# UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext in specific CGRect

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, screenshot, screen-capture

I want to take screen shot of the specific location in specific size. I found this. But it takes whole screen. Where can i set the CGRect.

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.window.bounds.size);
[self.window.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I was stuck on this a few days ago actually... Then after a while I managed to come up with a solution! I've implemented it in a category:

```
#import "UIView+RenderSubframe.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@implementation UIView (RenderSubframe)

- (UIImage *) renderWithSubframe:(CGRect)frame {  

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(frame.size, NO, 0.0);
    CGContextRef c = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextConcatCTM(c, CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-frame.origin.x, -frame.origin.y));
    [self.layer renderInContext:c];

    UIImage *screenshot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return screenshot;

}

@end
```

Voila!

If I'm not mistaken, this method doesn't actually render the unneeded part of the view at all, making this much more efficient than cropping the image afterwards.

In your case, you want to apply this category to a UIWindow class rather than a UIView.

Comment: I might be mistaking, but this method will not work properly on retina devices, since you're passing a 0.0 instead of `[UIScreen mainScreen].scale` as the `scale` parameter. You also do not multiply the size parameters to meet retina dimensions, this method will always return poor quality images

Comment: I'm using this code on retina devices and haven't run into that problem, the images return at the correct resolution. As far as I'm aware, using 0.0 automatically scales for retina devices.

Comment: @Eugene just checked the apple docs, 0.0 uses the main screen's scale factor, meaning that this code will work on retina devices fine without modification.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, guess, I've done some monkey business some time ago *>_>

Comment: Thank your very much. Worked like a charm.

Comment: @ArdaDogantemur great! If this answer's correct then make sure you accept it as the correct answer (hit the checkmark beside it).